# Trello user getting notifications for cards/boards she is not involved in or subscribed to?

Tags: trello

There is a user in our Trello organization who only needs to be notified when she is mentioned in a card. She has not subscribed to any boards.

The notification emails she gets are filled with notifications from cards she is not involved in. Why is this happening? How can I set it up so that she only gets notifications when she is @mentioned?

Comment: Is she subscribed to the list (not just the card or board)?
Is she an assigned member of that card(auto-subscribed)?